# It is possible to export the local_db bin to Google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, upload

I'm new in app engine.

I created an Java application using Google app engine. I populated a database offline. I can access it at my localhost. I know that the local dev server stores data in `local_db.bin`. 
When I upload the app to the online dev server, it doesn't upload my database. It is possible to upload the `local_db.bin`?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I read the documentation. But I only see how to backup and restore data. I don't know if it possible to upload the local_db.bin. I don't know if I should change the format's file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying/deploying the local_db.bin file directly to Google servers will have no effect and that file is intended only for the SDK that runs locally.  On production the datastore is a service and all implementation and files are hidden away from the user.  Thus you can't copy or change the format for the file to achieve what you want.

See this link for 
[datastore copy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#a_note_for_java_developers)

Depending how much data you have and how often you need to populate it then it might just be easier to re-populate it online, create some basic data bootstrapping code/script or an API/import process.